# Is there way to make the scrollbar become visible even when user is not scrolling the content

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I want to make the scrollbar become visible even when a user is not scrolling the content.

Here is the code:

```css
div{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   overflow:scroll;
}
div::-webkit-scrollbar{
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>Wikipedia is an online free-content encyclopedia project helping create a world in which everyone can freely share in the sum of all knowledge. It is supported by the Wikimedia Foundation and is based on a model of freely editable content. The name "Wikipedia" is a blending of the words wiki (a technology for creating collaborative websites, from the Hawaiian word wiki, meaning "quick") and encyclopedia. Wikipedia's articles provide links designed to guide the user to related pages with additional information.</div>
```

I try to set `visibility: visible;` to make the scrollbar be still visible when I am scrolling but seems not working.

Are there any ways that I could do that?

If not, could I make it become visible by customing the scrollbar?

Comment: Hi, easiest way to achive this is to have your `overflow: scroll` property encapsulated on a parent div.

Comment: @Blazorman ^ does not make the scrollbar always visible. That's what he already has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you can just set `html, body { overflow-y: scroll;}` if this page had scrollable content already in the body, and it would show. However, that will not work with a contained div on the page with no other content.

In this scenario, I would style a personalized scrollbar for the div so that it is always visible. These styles are for a standard scrollbar, but you can customize it as you desire.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<div>Wikipedia is an online free content encyclopedia project helping create a world in which everyone can freely share in the sum of all knowledge. It is supported by the Wikimedia Foundation and based on a model of freely editable content. The name "Wikipedia"
  is a blending of the words wiki (a technology for creating collaborative websites, from the Hawaiian word wiki, meaning "quick") and encyclopedia. Wikipedia's articles provide links designed to guide the user to related pages with additional information.</div>
```